# data does not update in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

i have a simple form like so

```
<form @submit.prevent="getSummary">
    <input type="text" v-model="userAcccount" placeholder="Enter Account 
    Number">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and the getSummary method in my methods object in vue is like this

```
methods: {
        getSummary () {               
            axios.get('core/handle.php', {
                params: {
                  accountNumber: this.userAcccount
                }
              })
              .then(function (response) {
                this.userData = response.data;
                console.log(this.userData);
              })
              .catch(function (error) {
                alert(error);
            });
        }
    }
```

my data object contains

```
data: {
        userAcccount: '',
        userData: []
    },
```

i am trying to update the userData with the response from axios and then use it to populate a table
 for testing purposes i just tried this

```
<span v-if="userData.length > 0">
      some data 
</span>
<span v-else>
      data not found
</span>
```

console.log shows me the userData has be updated but this bit of code above doesn't change.

Comment: what  console.log(response) print in your console ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have no access to the VM via `this` inside your `then` function. You have three ways to fix this:

1. Explicitly bind the outer `this` as execution context to the function (ES5 functions have their own this):

   ```
   .then(function (response) {
       this.userData = response.data; 
       console.log(this.userData);
   }.bind(this))
   ```
2. Store the `this` context in a local variable e.g. `self` or `that`:

   ```
   getSummary () {
     const self = this;
     axios.get('core/handle.php', {
       params: {
         accountNumber: this_.userAcccount
       }
     })
     .then(function (response) {
       self.userData = response.data;
       console.log(self.userData);
     })
     .catch(function (error) {
       alert(error);
     });
   }
   ```
3. Use ES6 arrow functions which don't have their own `this`:

   ```
   .then(response => {
     this.userData = response.data;
     console.log(this.userData);
   })
   ```

The concept of `this` in Javascript differs alot from many other programming languages as it describes the execution context of a function. It is not an easy-to-grab concept, but this helped me get into it:

> http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/

For reference, MDN is always a good place to go:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: thanks alot for the help the third option worked. i try to understand the other options and see how to use them.

Comment: You're welcome. This is one of the trickiest things to overcome when learning Javascript in more depth.

Comment: i dose not work for me, axios.get(url).then(response => {
                    this.items = response.data.response;
                }); but it not work and this.items is empty.

Answer (score 5):

Using ES6 arrow functions you can access the response in the callback by rewriting slightly, like so:

```
.then(response => {
    this.userData = response.data;
    console.log(this.userData);
})
```

This is because you are currently reaching the axios request context with `this`, which obviously is null as `userData` isn't in your scope. By using the arrow function syntax you get access to the parent component where `userData` resides.

Answer (score 3):

Save the Context of `this` and you are good to go.

```
methods: {
        getSummary () {
           var this_= this;
            axios.get('core/handle.php', {
                params: {
                  accountNumber: this_.userAcccount
                }
              })
              .then(function (response) {
                this_.userData = response.data;
                console.log(this_.userData);
              })
              .catch(function (error) {
                alert(error);
            });
        }
    }
```

If that doesn't work, add `this_.$forceUpdate();` to your response function after `this_.userData = response.data`, it will always work ;)

Comment: when you say "Save the Context of this and you are good to go." what do you mean